# Kivy: Button color after pressing changes only after (very) short hold

Tags: python, button, colors, kivy

It seems to me that the color change when clicking a button with a mouse only occurs if I hold the button pressed for a short time (< 1 second). If I only perform a very short click, it doesn't happen. Did anyone else experience this and is there a way to change this behaviour, so the button color changes immediately (preferably directly in the kv file)?

I am using Kivy 2.0.0.

Edit:
Meanwhile I noticed that this happens when the operations triggered by the button press take some time. Here is an example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time

import kivy
kivy.require('2.0.0')


Builder.load_string("""
<MyLayout>

    Button:
        text: "Button 1"
        on_press: root.button1_press()

    Button:
        text: "Button 2"
        on_release: root.button2_press()
""")


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    def button1_press(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Result Button 1")

    def button2_press(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Result Button 2")

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

To change the color of button 1 I need to press it for at least 3 seconds (the sleep time), while button 2 stays on for 3 seconds cause  `on_release` it used instead of `on_press` for binding.

Is there a way to just have a button change color immediately like a short "blink" to give the feedback that it has been pressed?

Comment: Try changing `min_state_time` time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this helps (I set `min_state_time` to 0.2), but there is still a short delay before the color change starts. Feels a bit "unresponsive". Can I change that, too?

Comment: Try setting value whatever suits.